# Selecting the last 12 weeks sales in pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query is producing data but the weeks that are only returning values are weeks 10,11,12 as they are in the last four months. I need to be able to get the week numbers for the last 12 weeks ie weeks 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 used in the pivot section but a formula like dateadd(week,-1,invoicedate) doesnt work

Im using sql server 2008 r2

thanks

```
SELECT productid, 
   [1]  AS 'This Week', 
   [2]  AS 'Last Week', 
   [3]  AS 'Week -3', 
   [4]  AS 'Week -4', 
   [5]  AS 'Week -5', 
   [6]  AS 'Week -6', 
   [7]  AS 'Week -7', 
   [8]  AS 'Week -8', 
   [9]  AS 'Week -9', 
   [10] AS 'Week -10', 
   [11] AS 'Week -11', 
   [12] AS 'Week -12' 
FROM   (SELECT productid, 
           qtyinvoiced, 
           Datepart(week, invoicedate) AS Tweek 
    FROM   dbo.invoicedetail 
    WHERE  invoicedate > Dateadd(m, -4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) source 
   PIVOT ( Sum(qtyinvoiced) 
         FOR tweek IN ( [1], 
                        [2], 
                        [3], 
                        [4], 
                        [5], 
                        [6], 
                        [7], 
                        [8], 
                        [9], 
                        [10], 
                        [11], 
                        [12] ) ) AS pvtmonth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
DATEPART(week, Invoicedate)  as Tweek
```

You can use

```
-DATEDIFF(WEEK, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, InvoiceDate) AS Tweek
```

This will give the difference in weeks between now and the invoice date, rather than the week number of the invoice date